# Skip some code and exit programm

Tags: c++

I have a simple question. How can i do this
Print Hello world, then goto 'anotherMessage', then print the message in that function, then skip the next cout "Dont print this" and exit,

Also, how would I exit programm, if i interchange the functions but keep statements same

```
void main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    anotherMessage();
    cout << "Dont print this";
}

void anotherMessage()
{
    cout << "Print this";
}
```

Comment: You can put  `exit(0)`  at the end of the `anotherMessage()` definition.

Comment: What if I want to keep printing hello world and Print this and skip the Don't Print this line?

Comment: Do you know the `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the type of anotherMessage() function as int, return an integer value ( 1 in the below code). Check if returned value is one, if yes, then exit from the program by calling exit(0).

```
void main()
{
cout << "Hello World";
int val = anotherMessage();
if(val) exit(0);
cout << "Dont print this";
}
int anotherMessage()
{
cout << "Print this";
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by πάντα ῥεῖ  you can use `exit(0)` at the end of the `anotherMessage()` definition.

`exit(0)` indicates successful program termination & it is fully portable, While

`exit(1)` (usually) indicates unsucessful termination. However, it's usage is non-portable.

If you're writing a function that could end up in a library for instance, calling exit from there is bad practice in general: it is much better to signal an error to the calling code (via a specific return value or exception for instance) and let the calling code decide what to do. (There are cases when it's perfectly valid though. e.g. if you're writing a function called quit_if_file_not_found, well, your users are expecting a termination.)

In your case, your parsing function probably shouldn't call exit: you might want, for example, at some point in the future, your main code to ask the user for a different file name if parsing the first one failed. If your parsing routine terminates the program, you have to modify both your main code and that function. If it had signaled an error condition, you'd only have to modify the logic in main.

(And don't just exit without printing an error message or logging something like you're doing above, that will make for frustrated users who can't know how to fix whatever issue it is the code encountered.)

Comment: How did you deduce from this vague question that OP is writing a parser and asking for file names? Are you Sherlock Holmes?

Comment: @molbdnilo : No, I just wanted to give where user of `exit()` is good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

A single exit() statement close your code instantly but is not a desired statement.

You could use a if statement when your function return a bool like this.

```
bool func();

func(){
// Do Stuff
return  // true or false
}

void main(){
    if(func()){
        // Do Stuff
    }else{
        //Do other Stuff
}
}
```